# Setting global font in swift

Tags: swift

I create an extension where I set custom font

```
extension UILabel {
    var substituteFontName : String {
        get { return self.font.fontName }
        set {
              self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font.pointSize)
        }
    }
}
```

but I have a problem: I get a error `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, but if I set static size like this

`self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: 13)`

I didn't get a error and fonts is changing. How can I set exactly size which was automatically

Comment: in set you have to use size: self.font?.pointSize ?? UIFont.labelFontSize

Answer (score 1):

The `font` attribute is actually implicitly unwrapped `UIFont!`, so you should change your `set` to:

```swift
self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font?.pointSize ?? UIFont.labelFontSize)
```